# UIBarButtonItem with custom action won't execute it

Tags: iphone

Well, figuring such thing was easy, I decided to get a custom action executed by my `UIBarButtonItem` once it's pressed. Here's the code:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"GET BACK!!!" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(test)];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:appsViewController animated:YES];
```

Yet, even without adding any custom views, `-test` isn't called at all (although the title change is applied).

As you can see, I'm applying these changes to the item right before I push the new view controller (else the title change wouldn't even work).

I've searched a lot for an answer to this, but the only trouble people seem to be having is it not replying to an action once it has a custom view. So; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set custom actions on back buttons. (Or, rather the action of the back button item is set to a internal one that does the back-behaviour.) If you want to do something when the user comes back to your view controller, consider doing it in `viewWillAppear:`. You might need to keep track of whether you're appearing after pushing a child view controller or appearing the first time, etc.

Comment: That can be probably tracked with an `NSUserDefaults` boolean. Yet, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using an instance variable on your view controller, not a NSUserDefaults value.

Comment: 10k for you, my friend! See you there in a few days ;)

Answer (score -1):

The back bar button item just allows you to configure the title to appear in the back button - it isn't stated in the docs but I think that, like a custom view, a custom action is ignored. It just pops the view controller.

Any button that looks like a back button and is in the left of the navigation bar *should* pop the top view controller from the stack. If you want to do anything else, use the left button item of the top view, or hook into the view will appear / disappear methods or the navigation controller delegate.